# Ubuntu with python 2

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-3.x, python-2.7

I was curious - if Python 3 is so widely spread, **why Ubuntu applications still use python 2?**

I have started to learn this language, and I am surprised that some application code I see uses python 2.7.x and when run in python 3 interpreter mostly causes fatal errors.

Should I concentrate on learning Python 2 instead or I have misunderstood something?

Comment: Worth a read: http://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3

Comment: I believe this is a valid question. Qs are closed way too quickly for being NC. Migrate this to askubuntu. And then we could provide an answer that Ubuntu has decided to shoot for the goal to port all remaining python2 scripts that are required for the core distribution to python3 for one of the next releases...

Comment: @cfi: "If Python 3 is so widely spread, why...." Uhm. That's not only off topic, it's a hypothetical question. Clearly not constructive. The question becomes non-hypothetical if you just ask "Why does Ubuntu 12.04 default to Python 2", and then the answer is "because Canonical and other Ubuntu folks has had spent time/money to move to Python 3 yet" which is a DUH-type answer, so also not constructive. And even then, there is two separate questions.

Comment: @Lennart: That's a constructive comment. Re your first point: One could just suggest to the asker to remove that half-sentence (and I agree with your point here), or edit it out. As to your suggested "Why...", I disagree that the only answer would be "It cost money". There may be other reasons. And since Canonical reads & answers on askubuntu, and this Q is purely Ubuntu related it should be moved. Just _assuming_ there won't be a better answer than your first guess, and closing the question is unfair, imho

Comment: @Gundars: May I suggest to work with Lennart's comment and reduce your question to one question? Also remove things that appear polemic or suggestive. Probably it's a good idea to just ask on askubuntu.com

Comment: @cfi: I'm not assuming. That *is* the answer. :) But yeah, Gundars can try asking it on askubuntu, but even better, ask "When is Ubuntu going to use Python 3 as it's main Python?". That's a constructive question that has a meaningful answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many places with a currently working code base still use Python v 2.x since some third-party software/libraries haven't been brought up to Python v3.x yet, but the move to v3 is inevitable in the long run.

Your Python 2 code may not work under v 3 depending on what you are doing. Here is [What's New in Python 3](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html) so you can see some of the differences yourself (Also take a look at the helpful link @Mark posted above).

If you are starting out to learn Python from scratch and don't need access to 3rd party libraries that only work with v2 I would go ahead and learn v3, otherwise learning v2 is fine. The differences between v2 and v3 can be worked out without too much trouble down the line if needed and since most what you learn about programming with Python will still apply.